# Encrypt zip archive using PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, zip, password-encryption

I have a PowerShell script function that creates a text file and then creates a zip file and encrypts it. The code that I have written is as below.

```
function Zip-File([String]$Name, [String]$getRandomPass, [String]$EncryptionKey) {
    try {
        $7ZipPath = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe";
        $Filepath = "C:\Scripts\$Name.txt";
        $ZipPath = "C:\Scripts\$Name.zip";

        Set-Content -Path $Filepath -Value $getRandomPass -Force;

        $arguments = "a -tzip ""$ZipPath"" ""$Filepath"" -mx9 -p$EncryptionKey";
        $windowstyle = "Normal";
        $p = Start-Process $7ZipPath -ArgumentList $arguments -Wait -Passthru -WindowStyle $windowstyle;
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Error is: $($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)"
        Write-Host "Error is: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    } finally {}
}
```

This code creates the zip folder `$Name.zip` with the file `$Name.txt`. However, only the file `$Name.txt` is encrypted with the encryption key. The zip archive `$Name.zip` is not encrypted.

I am not sure how to encrypt the `$Name.zip` zip archive. Could someone point out how to encrypt the `$Name.zip` zip archive?

Comment: What do you mean by archive is not being encrypted? Zip format doesn't encrypt file names within the archive, only the contents. What's more, classic zip encryption is not that secure.

Comment: when i create the above $name.zip file and then try to open it (double click), the zip file opens without asking for a password. When I attempt to open the file $name.txt within the zip file, then it asks for a password. Whai I need is that the password is asked when I  double click the $name.zip file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to protect your filenames, you can double archive it. Basically, you can again zip the .zip file. This should work.